# make a client screenshot through canvas

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas

I am trying to create a screenshot of a webpage with html2canvas. I am new to canvas and I think that that is the reason why I cannot get the [html2canvas.js](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) library to work right.

Please see, http://jsfiddle.net/cantdutchthis/7sCya/.

The javascript, after loading in the html2canvas.js file, runs the following;

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas)
    }
});
```

The body contains three objects, a paragraph tag, an image with a uri source and a [placeholder kitten](http://placekitten.com/).

Why is canvas only making a print screen of the paragraph and the uri source, why not the kitten?

Comment: Because the kitten is from another domain. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/CORS_Enabled_Image

Comment: Check limitations: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html#limitations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not allowed because of the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). It only works if the image has the same protocol and host as the script.

See this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7sCya/1/) with a local image (press `run` again if you do not see relative image `../../favicon.png` one the first load).

You either need a proxy like demonstrated on the [html2canvas website](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html) or add a special flag to your browser on startup or load the image from a [cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) enabled server like proposed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16873920/696973).